# Writing Multiple Objects in Different Nodes in Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, rest, parse-platform, firebase

I am using Firebase REST API to add some objects to multiple nodes from Parse Cloud Code

However, this overwrites the nodes!

(using hardcoded values here for the sake of clarity)

```
var chatPayload = { 
                   "rooms": 
                     {
                       "animalRoom" : true,
                     },
                    "members": 
                      {
                        "animalRoom": 
                          {
                            "chrisTheCat": true,
                            "hankTheHog"  : true
                           }
                      }
                    }

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'https://myapp.firebaseIO.com/' + '.json',
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(chatPayload)
    (...)
  })
```

I have fiddled with explicit ref declaration (as suggested in their [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html#section-update)) using string concatenation for the actual variables i.e.:

```
'{
  "rooms/' + animalRoom + '": "true",
  "members/' + animalRoom + '/' + chrisTheCat '": "true",
  "members/' + animalRoom + '/' + hankTheHod '": "true",
}'
```

However this just writes one big string to the root ref.

I have read the Firebase docs pretty thoroughly and am aware that a potential solution is to append the child node to the `url` in the request. However, I'm updating multiple nodes, and would like to achieve this one go.

I have also tried switching `PUT` to `PATCH` but that actually doesn't write anything.

Any ideas?

**ANSWER**: this is not possible. Parse does not support PATCH requests

Comment: REST-wise, that's what a PUT is supposed to do: overwrite the given resource with the given data. What Firebase does, I don't know. If you want to overwrite a 'sub resource', you change the path name to `my/collection/item.json` etc.

Comment: @Rudie When I switch it to `PATCH`, requests actually don't do anything .....

Comment: @Rudie the thing is that I'm trying to write to multiple paths

Comment: The docs say you should use the client's `update()` method: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-update I don't know what `update()` does, but I'm sure you can find out. Or to use `PATCH`, hm.. https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html#section-update

Comment: @Rudie I actually tried `PATCH`, but the data is unaffected

Comment: This seems to work: https://gist.github.com/rudiedirkx/4a083247460461e9fa3c so you have to give the entire object, or the only property you want to overwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, Firebase seems to do what it promises, using PUT and PATCH correctly (as documented):

```
curl -X PUT -d '"Jeff"' users/jeff/name.json
curl -X PUT -d '"Carla"' users/carla/name.json
curl -X PATCH -d '{"jeff/city": "Houston", "carla/city": "Atlantis"}' users.json
curl -X PATCH -d '{"jeff/family": {"children": 1, "parents": 0, "siblings": 1}, "carla/family": {"children": 4, "parents": 2, "siblings": 3}}' users.json
curl -X PATCH -d '{"jeff/family/children": 2, "carla/family/parents": 0}' users.json
```

results in:

```
{
  "carla":{"city":"Atlantis","family":{"children":4,"parents":0,"siblings":3},"name":"Carla"},
  "jeff":{"city":"Houston","family":{"children":2,"parents":0,"siblings":1},"name":"Jeff"}
}
```

which is correct.

In your case, the PATCH keys would be (literally, no vars)

- rooms/animalRoom
- members/animalRoom/chrisTheCat
- members/animalRoom/hankTheHog

I don't know why you have `animalRoom` and `chrisTheCat` variables..?

Booleans seem to work as well (literal, no strings):

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"animalRoom": false}' test/rooms.json
curl -X PUT -d '{"animalRoom": {"chrisTheCat": false, "hankTheHog": false}}' test/members.json
curl -X PATCH -d '{"rooms/animalRoom": true, "members/animalRoom/chrisTheCat": true}' test.json
```

results in

```
{
    "members":{"animalRoom":{"chrisTheCat":true,"hankTheHog":false}},
    "rooms":{"animalRoom":true}
}
```

which is also correct.

In your case, using JS in Parse, you're sending JSON encoded `chatPayload`. That's good, I think, although I don't know how Parse supports PATCH and PUT. Try this:

```
var chatPayload = {
  "rooms/animalRoom": true,
  "members/animalRoom/chrisTheCat": true,
  "members/animalRoom/hankTheHog": true
};
```

(literal strings, no variables, no quotes around the booleans)

It might very well be that Parse doesn't support PUT and PATCH, and doesn't know what to do with the given data. I'm sure you can look that up in the `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` docs.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I notice that you are creating the paths individually and _then_ doing multiple updates. What I want to do is to do create the room and its members all at once (creating multiple paths at once). btw thanks for answering

Comment: You can create everything at once, or in parts like I did. Only the `PATCH` requests are relevant to my answer. The rest is data set-up. As you can see in the PATCH requests, I edit multiple resources at once.

Comment: I am not able to get this to work. I tried again and again, tweaking, but as I mentioned in the question comments, PATCH does not affect my data when there is none _and_ when there is some

Comment: Furthermore, i am using javascript and I am not very comfortable with it, nor am i with curl, so please answer in javascript

Comment: I've updated my answer, at the end. How are you making an app in JS/Parse when you're not very comfortable with it..?

Comment: Wow you nailed it same time as me. Parse does not support PATCH. And I'm actually making an iOS app, but I need Parse to speak with Firebase, so I have no choice but to use JS.